# jQuery addClass within a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a few `foreach` loops with a trigger and a content div. The intent is for the trigger to be clicked, then `addClass` to content div, making it visible on screen.

**foreach markup**

```
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : ?>

    <a class="slide-trigger" href="#loc<?php echo $post->ID;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <span> 

    <?php 

    $speakers = get_field('speakers');

    ?>
    <?php if( $speakers ): ?>
        <ul class="flat">
        <?php foreach( $speakers as $speaker ): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $speaker->ID ); ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_title( $speaker->ID ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </span>

    <div class="slide" id="loc<?php echo $post->ID;?>">

        <div class="close"></div>       
        <?php echo $post->post_title;?>
        <?php echo $post->post_content;?>

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".slide-toggle[href^='#loc']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".slide[id^='loc']").addClass("open");
})

$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".slide").removeClass("open");
});
```

What I'm looking for is each `slide-toggle` to trigger it's `slide`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The ID is in the href, so just grab it and remove the `#loc` prefix, then you can select the corresponding slide to open. Also this way, the startsWith selector is no longer required.

```
$(".slide-toggle[href^='#loc']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".slide[id='loc" + this.href.replace('#loc', '') + "']").addClass("open");
})
```

---

Having to parse out the ID, then concatenate like this seems a bit hacky. It would be nicer to use `data-*` attributes.

Link:

```
<a class="slide-trigger" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" href="#loc<?php echo $post->ID;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

Slide:

```
<div class="slide" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" id="loc<?php echo $post->ID;?>">
```

jQuery:

```
$(".slide-toggle[data-id]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".slide[data-id=" + $(this).data('id') + "]").addClass("open");
})
```

Comment: by all accounts this should work, but it's not firing. any thoughts?

Comment: ah, got it. the `$post->ID` is a number, which wasn't working. simply adding a letter in front of the data-id solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@MrCode had two great solutions to this. The `data-id` method is a bit more elegant and what I went with.

Note, the `$post->ID` is a number which just won't work as an `id=` - https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/ - and was causing the issue where things just wouldn't work.

The answer; follow @MrCode's method of using a data attribute. It's elegant and works great w/ the loop.